# Return Storage Variable From Function In Solidity

Tags: solidity, storage, solidity-0.8.x

Is it possible to return a variable with the data location type of `storage` from a function?

Consider the smart contract below, **which DOES NOT compile**:

```solidity
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.16;

library MappingDataTypes {
    struct UintMappingValue {
        uint256 value;
        bool isSet;
    }
}

contract Storage {
    mapping(address => MappingDataTypes.UintMappingValue) uintStorage;

    // ISSUE HERE: TypeError: Data location must be "memory" or "calldata" for return parameter in function, but "storage" was given.
    function getUnitStorage(address ownerAddr) public returns (MappingDataTypes.UintMappingValue storage) {
        return uintStorage[ownerAddr];
    }


    function storeValue(uint256 value) public {
        // if return value of getUintStorage() function is set to (MappingDataTypes.UintMappingValue memory), the compilation fails with the following error:
        // TypeError: Type struct MappingDataTypes.UintMappingValue memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type struct MappingDataTypes.UintMappingValue storage pointer
        MappingDataTypes.UintMappingValue storage storedValue = getUnitStorage(msg.sender);
        storedValue.isSet = true;
        storedValue.value = value;
    }


}
```

The goal is to return a struct from the `uintStorage` mapping and then modify it in the `storeValue()` function. The changes should persist in the contract's storage and reflected in the `uintStorage` mapping value.

The contract above does not compile with the following error: `TypeError: Data location must be "memory" or "calldata" for return parameter in function, but "storage" was given.`. If the if return value of `getUintStorage()` function is set to `(MappingDataTypes.UintMappingValue memory)`, another error occurs due to not being able to cast from a `memory` variable into a `storage` variable: `TypeError: Type struct MappingDataTypes.UintMappingValue memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type struct MappingDataTypes.UintMappingValue storage pointer`.

How can the goal of returning a `storage` struct from a function, or equivalent, be achieved?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works if you declare it as internal.

```
function getUnitStorage(address ownerAddr) internal returns (MappingDataTypes.UintMappingValue storage) {
    return uintStorage[ownerAddr];
}
```

Public and external functions cannot return storage references.